# How to supress the warning about NoClassDefFoundError with 'Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class'?

Tags: android, classloader

An android.net.wifi.WifiManager$ScanResultsCallback field declared in my class. This is a new class provided in API level 30.
If my app runs on early Android version, the ART will give me a throwed inforatmion:

```
I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<xxxx>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/net/wifi/WifiManager$ScanResultsCallback;
```

My code will not instantiate the object when runing on old android. So it will not crash.

And I know reflection can resolve it by making this class aware only on latest android version.

My question is, is there any other simple method to resolve it? Can androidx's annotation help me?